# How to apply inverse hyperbolic sine using the repices package in R?

Tags: r, r-recipes

I am exploring the `recipes` package to prepare my data for linear regression. But even a simple transformation of two variables using inverse hyperbolic sine does not yield the results I am expecting. What am I getting wrong here?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(recipes)

set.seed(1)

df <- tibble(
  x = runif(4) * 10,
  y = runif(4) * 10
)

# manual transformation
df %>% 
  mutate(x = asinh(x),
         y = asinh(y))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1.70  1.45
#> 2  2.02  2.89
#> 3  2.45  2.94
#> 4  2.90  2.59

# transformation using recipes
rec_obj <- recipe(y ~ x, data = df)

rec_obj %>% 
  step_hyperbolic(x, y, func = "sin", inverse = TRUE) %>% 
  prep() %>%
  bake(new_data = NULL)
#> Warning in func(getElement(new_data, col_names[i])): NaNs produced

#> Warning in func(getElement(new_data, col_names[i])): NaNs produced
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   NaN   NaN
#> 2   NaN   NaN
#> 3   NaN   NaN
#> 4   NaN   NaN
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for reporting this! This is a bug in recipes, and I [have set up the fix here](https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/pull/932).